# Como podria obtener al presionar el hipervinculo la dirección href generada dentro de un for

Tags: php, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo el problema de que he generado los hipervinculo con una iteración debido a que me evita repetir código, necesito obtener esa variable al clicar en el hipervinculo para poder ponerla en un div y que me muestre ese contenido.

Este es el código que me genera los hipervinculos:

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <?php  $directorio2= '../packs/pack'.$i;
                $rowNum2= scandir($directorio2);
                $num2=count($rowNum2);
              ?>
              <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $num2-2; $x++): ?>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#<?=$i.$x?>">Ejercicio <?= $x ?></a>
               <?php endfor; ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: captura la url de la ventana que abres

Comment: vale, 2 min y actualizo, no se abre ninguno ventana

Comment: solo PHP o tambien JS/JQUERY?

Comment: no tengo problema con el lenguaje siempre que me lo solucione

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haria:

1º añadir una clase a estos links, por ejemplo `random`

```
<a class="dropdown-item random" href=.....>
```

2º Crear el evento click sobre las etiquetas `<a>` con clase `random` (JQ)

algo asi:

```
     $(a.random).each(function( index, element ) {
         $(this).click(function {
             alert($(this).attr("href"))
         })      
     });
```

si esto te vale, seguimos.
Ya me dices

Comment: hasta aqui perfecto, pero el evento clic no se como funciona

Comment: por cada link, que tenga esa clase, le decimos que si salta el evento click haga el alert

Comment: y en vez de hacer un alert, almacenas el texto o lo que sea

Comment: vale, es decir, al presionar ejercicio 1 hacemos que me haga una alerta 1 por ejemplo y lo guardoHasta aqui bien, ahora como hago que esa alerta sea el numero del ejercicio o del href

Comment: $(this).attr("href") lee el contenido del atributo href (como cadena de texto)

Comment: aaah vale, entonces me queda el href, que seria? #1 o 1

Comment: lo que tenga el atributo. si quieres quitar los # seria: alert($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1])

Comment: que lo que hace es cortar por el caracter #

Comment: espero te sirva

Comment: solo una duda mas que jamás he hecho funciones con jq, para sacarlo en una variable pones return el valor del alert o solo llamas a la funcion?

Comment: puedes hacer el return o directamente asociar el valor a una variable, como te guste mas

Comment: voy a probarlo y si veo que no me salgo abriré una pregunta nueva relacionada con jq, muchas gracias